# About validity of a marriage due to swear by the name of Allah

Tags: oaths

Assalamu Alaikum,

A man likes a woman. one day they had a quarrel and due to anger, the man did a swear by the name of Allah, that he would not continue the relation anymore. After the man regrets for this, wants to withdraw the swear and wants to marry the woman. Now the question is, if the man marries the woman, will the marriage be valid in the view of Islam ?

Answer (score 1):

> Allah will not impose blame upon you for what is meaningless in your oaths, but He will impose blame upon you for [breaking] what you intended of oaths. So its expiation is the feeding of ten needy people from the average of that which you feed your [own] families or clothing them or the freeing of a slave. But whoever cannot find [or afford it] - then a fast of three days [is required]. That is the expiation for oaths when you have sworn. But guard your oaths. Thus does Allah make clear to you His verses that you may be grateful. ([Al-Ma'idah 5:89](http://quran.com/5/89))

It's accepted to break an oath if you made one out of anger, or something unintentional. But **the person breaking the oath must feed ten needy people, clothe them, or free a slave**. If he cannot afford that, then he should **fast for three days**.

I could find nothing saying that the marriage would be invalid, but breaking an oath without paying the 'fine' would be a sin.